# Run a method from a C++ program with Qt without writing entire program in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to run a certain method from a C++ program with Qt with certain input parameters when for instance a button is clicked *without writing the complete program in Qt itself*?

Let's say that I have a project in Visual Studio with a corresponding .exe and I want to run the method example with input parameter 5 whenever a button is clicked. How could I do that?

Comment: This makes little sense. What is the button doing? Why are you using Qt? What use case does this have?

Comment: @Qix I want to build an interface. How else should I do it then?

Comment: What method are you trying to call? Why is this one Qt method better than some much-smaller option?

Comment: @Qix I don't want to call a method from Qt, I want to call a method from the program that I wrote in Visual Studio. What other option would you suggest then to make an interface without having to recode my whole project in Qt?

Comment: It's not going to work like that. Qt wraps a **lot** of the underlying system's graphics API and requires a pretty hardy state be built up before methods will really mean anything at runtime.

Comment: If the program in Visual Studio is a DLL, then I suppose you could load it.

Comment: @Qix There is completely no basis for your comment. I stated clearly what I want. I don't like your tone at all. Maybe you should follow a lesson on how to communicate with other things than only computers.

Comment: @jliv902 Load it where? Loading a DLL doesn't inherently let you call methods to classes that aren't instantiated. Qt requires you have a `Qt::Application` set up to even start event handling.

Comment: Are you talking about running some console executable inside a Qt application feeding it command line parameters every time you press some button in your Qt application is pressed?

Comment: @user3482499 I'm asking for clarification as to **what you're trying to accomplish** and instead you're wasting our time by complaining about us taking time out of our day to try to help. Perhaps spending some time on either the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) or even [SO Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) would be pertinent to your time here.

Comment: @user3482499 you absolutely did not clearly state what you want. We have to guess here.

Comment: @drescherjm That is exactly what I mean. Would there be a way to do that?

Comment: You do that with QProcess.

Comment: See my first comment: `What is the button doing? Why are you using Qt? What use case does this have?`

Comment: Or my second: `What method are you trying to call? Why is this one Qt method better than some much-smaller option?`

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. Could you give me an example on how I could do that or refer me to any documentation on it? Because I heard about QProcess before, but I could not find an example where they run a single method through an interface like I wanted for instance.

Comment: @Qix See my op `run a certain method from a C++ program` `when the button is clicked`. If you don't want to help in a constructive manner, I suggest that you just leave this post instead of completely defacing it.

Comment: I am looking for an example at the moment. I have some in my code but then I would have to simplify.

Comment: @user3482499 Which method? Why is Qt involved? Why isn't a standard button handler working?

Comment: @Qix A method from my own program, as I specified. I need Qt to build an interface obviously. I don't know how else I could build interfaces as easily.

Comment: @user3482499 But you said your code **isn't** using Qt.

Comment: > `without writing the complete program in Qt itself?`

Comment: @Qix Exactly. So I want to call a method through Qt of a program that is not written in Qt. So I don't want to recode the whole program in Qt.

Comment: A reasonable example of using QProcess to execute a console application is here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28406-QProcess-Calling-console-program?p=134134#post134134

Comment: Why not call the method directly?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you :). I will try out if I can do something similar.

Comment: @Qix Because I want my program to be distributable to people without coding knowledge, so that they can just press buttons instead.

Comment: @drescherjm Is explaining how to run a console program using Qt. Either your wording is completely wrong or you're misunderstanding what he's trying to help you with.

Comment: @user3482499 `I want my program to be distributable` What do you mean by this? You want to distribute as a DLL? `so that they can just press buttons instead` **you're still not explaining what is going on that isn't working**.

Comment: @Qix I want a .exe that they can double click, then press a button so that something happens. It's that simple.

Comment: @user3482499 Okay, that part is clear. Why is Qt involved? What are you doing with Qt?

Comment: @Qix I want to build an interface. I don't know an other way to build intefaces as easily as in Qt.

Comment: @user3482499 So your program *is* created using Qt?

Comment: @Qix No. My *interface* is created with Qt. The program logic is coded in Visual Studio.

Comment: How are you creating your interface? How is it **not** in Visual Studio? How is it in a language other than C++? Visual Studio is just an IDE for writing C++ on Windows.

Comment: @Qix Qt allows me to easily and very quickly (even using drag and drop) make interfaces. Visual studio does not (at least not as easily). But I prefer writing the program logic in Visual studio still. So that's why I want to combine both.

Comment: So you're using Qt creator?

Comment: @Qix Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ah there's one miscommunication. Remember that Qt by itself is a graphics **library** written in C++ that [abstracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) away a lot of the heavy lifting for each specific platform. Qt Creator, on the other hand, is a program that allows you to create interfaces using drag-and-drop versus programmatically creating GUIs. Anything you do in Qt Creator is ultimately translated to equivalent C++ code.

Comment: So you're saying your program **is** created using the Qt library; your interface **is** created using Qt Creator; the *rest* of your logic is being hand-coded in visual studio. And now you want to interact with your GUI you've created from visual studio?

Comment: @Qix Ok I understand. Does that mean that it is not possible? What way would you suggest to build an interface for the program that I wrote in Visual Studio in the easiest manner?

Comment: @Qix I think I do not know enough of Qt to answer your question. I really just thought I could make an interface in Qt creator an somehow link that to my visual studio project.

Comment: You probably can, but Qt Creator itself is [actually not a bad alternative to Visual Studio](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-editor-functions.html).

Comment: Qt Creator allows you handle what goes on when events fire in your code so you can program the logic behind the interface without actually having to code the interface manually. If you're using Qt Creator, you'll still need to understand how Qt working under the hood (to a degree) in order to find and implement code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Qix Ok, thank you. I think the current answer actually already comes very close to what I had in mind. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt operates by creating a `QWidget` window, and then an event loop.

Your code to create a window, and then a button that triggers another function is trivial.

Many of the examples Qt provides show this functionality.

To get started, Download Qt.  Download the Qt Add-On for Visual Studio.  Note, that the express edition of visual studio doesn't work with the Qt Add-On.

After you have all that done, create a Qt project from the Qt classes that are available.  In this case, I would not choose QML/Qt Quick, but just a Qt Widgets class, such as `QWidget` or `QDialog` or `QMainWindow`.

Using the Qt Add-On should ensure that you have the libraries found and available to Visual Studio.

Make sure that you can get a Hello World example is buildable and running using a Qt Widget of some sort.

The code it generates for you should look like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

To add in a button, you need to place it on a Widget and then connect a SLOT to its `clicked()` signal.  The following is a compact way to do it.

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>

static void someFunction ()
{
    qDebug() << "Button was clicked";
    // run my other function that requires a parameter of 5

    qDebug() << "Run my other function with 5!";
    // otherFunction(5);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Click Me");
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, someFunction);

    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
    vbox->addWidget(button);

    w.setLayout(vbox);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

To make a powerful GUI, you will want to leverage more than just a functor, and use QObjects and let it use the moc compiler and create your own signals and slots for all your custom functions.

Connecting to a functor is new with Qt 5.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html

A more verbose way to do it, but allows for more expandability and OOP, is to subclass QWidget or QMainWindow, like it generated for you, and put a method in your subclassed function that you put under your `slots` list in your header file.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Take the time to understand signals and slots and you can create almost any GUI you can imagine using Qt.  Good luck.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this exactly what I what I as looking for! I appreciate your effort!

Comment: I remember my first GUI I wanted to make, and I asked this exact same question to a few people, and got some less than helpful answers.  The initial learning curve is a little steep, but its not bad.  Good luck.

Comment: I encountered the exact same problem. There is not that much information available for true beginners. Thanks a lot for sharing your findings!

Comment: I installed everything like you said, but now when I copy for instance the first sample program that you wrote, VS underlines all the include statements in red (it cannot find the header files). So I went to project -> properties and then to 'additional include directories', but I am not sure which folders I should select there. Do you know which ones I should select? Or is there something else that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I should probably add that I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate with the add on for the VS 2012 edition.

Comment: A Qt project includes several dependencies.  There are bunch of dll's that Qt uses.  This environment is setup for running in Visual studio when you create a Qt Project.  Can you copy your other code into the Qt project instead of the other way around?

Comment: Ah, how stupid. However, it still does not work for me. What I now did is 1. I opened a Qt project file 2. create basic .pro file 3. Copy the code of the first simple project underneath the then already existent lines of code (is this last step also correct?). I then get the following error `Qt5Widgetsd.lib(Qt5Widgetsd.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'`. What am I doing wrong still?

Comment: Qt dll's are built with specific compilers for specific architectures.  If you change your target build to x64 from x86, then you can use the Qt libraries you downloaded.  If you download the x86 qt libraries for windows, then you can build 32 bit apps, too.

Comment: How can I change the target build? And why would I actually not be able to build 64 bit apps?

Comment: In visual studio, in the project navigator, right click on your project's folder/name > `Properties`.  Across the top of the Properties page it shows `Configuration`, `Active(Debug)`, Platform: `Active(Win32)`.  Change platform to x64.  If it isn't available there, then go and add it under the `Configuration Manager` button.  Also to change the active build you are using, use the drop downs in the toolbars across the top of Visual Studio (near the green arrow).

Comment: Thanks, everything works now :)

Comment: I'm struggeling quite a lot still so I would really appreciate it if you could help me further. I have now built a Hello world example by using the procedure as described here: http://sschaub.wikidot.com/tutorial-on-qt-with-visual-studio So I have a separate header file with the slot for the push button in my interface. However what they do there is `ui.btnHello->setText("Hi!");` but what I want is to run my own function and show the number that that function outputs. I have tried replacing the setText by my own function, but as that is not in the header file that is not recognised.(1)

Comment: How can I make it such that it recognises that function (it is defined in `main.cpp`). And what can I then do to show the result that the function produces? Again, thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it :)!

Comment: That is another question for StackOverflow.  Basically to reference a function from a header, you need to tell the linker it exists and the compiler needs to be able to build it.  So header files describe the function name, type and parameter list for functions and typically source files have the guts of the functions.  Also header and source files make OOP very easy.  Qt relies heavily on OOP, and associating any function as a method to an object.  Try reading through this link: http://www.tiem.utk.edu/~gross/c++man/tutorial.html